# DCL information between process and subprocess

Tags: vms, dcl

I'm trying to pass information between main process and subprocess ( learning how this all works in the process) I need to get information from the subprocess, in this case the value of g_start.   This is the way i seen online to handle this, if there is a better way please let me know!

Main file contains

```
$ define/job/nolog g_start false
$ g_test == 6
$ spawn @test.com
$ if f$trnlnm(g_start) .eqs. true
$ then
```

File test.com contains:

```
$ If g_test .nes. 5 
$ then
$ define/job g_start true
$ endif
$ logout
```

When running the main file g_test is not found what am I doing wrong that I'm not getting data to pass back and forth between main processes and subprocesses.

Comment: You probably meant to thave quotation marks around the logical name: `f$trnlnm( "g_start" )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DCL symbols (`g_test`) aren't shared between processes.  Using shared logical names, e.g. in the job table, will work.

More advanced communications, e.g. passing messages, may be done using mailboxes.

**EDIT**: To clarify, `spawn/symbols` will cause symbols to be copied to the subprocess on creation, but that creates a new set of symbols.  The parent process then goes its merry way and any symbol updates in either process occur independently.

Comment: So the $ define/job g_start true does not set the shared logical name?  Completely new to VMS/DCL sorry

Comment: @user1943219 - Yes, `define/job` sets the value of the shared logical.  Any process in the job, aka process tree, can create/read/update/delete (CRUD) logicals in the job table.  Since the table is shared, all of the processes will see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, typo on my part i guess.

File 1:

```
$ define/job g_start false
$ g_test == 6
$ spawn @test.com
$ result = f$trnlnm("g_start")
$ write sys$output ''result'
$ if (''result' .eq. "true")
$ then
```

File 2:

```
$ If g_test .nes. 5 
$ then
$ define/job g_start true
$ endif
$ logout
```

Comment: Taking out the `spawn` does simplify things.  Another typo?

Comment: Yes, when copy/paste from notepad I missed the spawn command, it was in the working copy. updated above